# Error installing PyTorch when building Docker image

Tags: docker, pytorch, docker-image

I run into this error when trying to build a Docker image. My requirements.txt file only contains 'torch==1.9.0'. This version clearly exists, but after downloading for a minute or longer, this error pops up.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does the error also occur with another pytorch version (e.g. 1.8.2) and with the CPU-only version (1.9.0+cpu)?

Comment: It looks like only certain torch versions are available, none of which appear to be CPU-only. It should be a memory issue. However, trying to install the smaller 1.8.0 version (735 MB) also generates this error.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pytorch docker container on docker hub that has the latest releases: https://hub.docker.com/r/pytorch/pytorch/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated

Maybe you can either base your docker container on that container (if it works for you) or you can compare the Dockerfile of your container with the Dockerfile of the container on docker hub to see if you are missing any system level dependencies or configurations...

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `Dockerfile` to install requirements using:

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
```

This will solve ram/memory related issues with large packages like torch.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as a memory issue. Make sure to remove any unused containers and images. You can list your images by `docker images` and then remove them by `docker rmi <image code>`

If you want a completely fresh slate you can purge all your cached data by `docker system prune`. Be careful because this will delete all active containers and images as well as cached data but it worked for me.